# Парсинг JSON в DropDownList ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Привет есть код.
Контролер

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("db.json"))
        {
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SelectListItem>>(json);
            ViewBag.List = items;
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Вьюшка

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Лаба";
    var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var c in ViewBag.List)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = c.Id, Value = c.Name });
    }
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownList("Name", listItems)
    </div>
</div>
```

Так вот вылетает эксепш

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ""System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" не содержит определения для "Id""

показывает что `ViewBag` не пустой имеет 3 значения
вот JSON

```
[
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": "Саша"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Даша"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Маша"
  }
]
```

что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема у Вас в том что Вы пытаетесь свою структуру (`Id`, `Name`) привести к `SelectListItem`, что конечно же не есть хорошо в Вашем случае. И соответсвенно Вы получаете `RuntimeBinderException` потому что Вы попытались десеариализовать Вашу структуру к `SelectListItem` который не содержить свойства/поля `Id` и `Name`.

Хот фикс вот:

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);
ViewBag.List = items;

return View();
```

А по хорошему создайте класс, который може представлять Вашу структуру, например:

```
public class Entity // тут какое-то смысловое имя структуры.
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

и код в контролере будет таким:

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(json);
ViewBag.List = items;

return View();
```

Comment: спасибо помогло!!1

Comment: @Санитариум, обновил ответ с более приемлимым решением. А потом так же посмотрите как делать строго-типизирование View, это потенциально избавит Вас от ошибок в рантайме.